# Why KeyError raises even the respective key exists?

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

```
def countLetter(string):
    dic = dict()
    for char in string:
        dic[char] = (1,dic[char]+1)[char in dic]
    print(dic)
countLetter('aabcb')
```

Here, I'm trying to count the number of times each letter has occured, but the line 4 raises an error.
It raises an **KeyError**.

Comment: *"even the respective key exists?"* It doesn't exist. That's why you get a `KeyError`. Your `dic` is empty when you create it, and you don't try to add something at `dic[char]` until you've already tried accessing the value of `dic[char]` on the right-hand-side of that assignment.

Comment: But, it is evaluated only if the condition is true. and the condition is checking the existence of the key in the dictionary

Comment: It is evaluated unconditionally, since you did not write `if` anywhere.

Comment: @kaya3: Technically, you could still have lazy evaluation without `if`, e.g. via the old (error-prone, but functional in this case) approach to selecting between two options before [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/): `dic[char] = char in dic and dic[char] + 1 or 1`

Comment: Yes, `if` is not the only language construct which conditionally evaluates - you could even write `while condition: do_thing(); break` if you really wanted to. But the code doesn't use any such construct, that's the point.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this line:

```
dic[char] = (1,dic[char]+1)[char in dic]
```

is *eagerly* evaluating `dic[char]+1` as part of constructing the `tuple` to index *before* you get around to testing if `char in dic` to select the element of the `tuple`. So it dies with a `KeyError` before your test has a chance to prevent the failing lookup. To make it lazy, you could do:

```
dic[char] = dic[char] + 1 if char in dic else 1
```

or you could just use [a method designed for this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to avoid the explicit test:

```
dic[char] = dic.get(char, 0) + 1
```

Though this particular pattern is made even simpler with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

def countLetter(string):
    print(collections.Counter(string))  # print(dict(collections.Counter(string))) if it must look like a dict
```

Comment: yup! the lazy approach works.But, I don't get how the get method works?

Comment: @Surya: Read the docs I linked. `get` never raises exceptions; if the key doesn't exist, it returns the second argument instead (`None` if no second argument is given).